# Why must nullable primitives be casted as non null before returning from method in C#, yet complex objects do not?

Tags: c#

I came across an interesting facet of the C# language this morning I have not experienced yet; consider the below code snippet:

```
    public class Example
    {

        public int getInt()
        {
            int? myInt = 2;

            return myInt; // <-- compiler error.
        }

        public object getObject()
        {
            object? obj = new { };

            return obj; // <-- OK, no error.
        }
    }
```

The compiler returns an error on the commented line above:
`Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)`

What I find interesting is that the object example works just fine without complaining. I am assuming this is something to do with primitives vs. objects but I am unable to find any resources. I am aware the return type is not matching the object type, I just thought it was curious that it works with objects and not a primitive. If anyone could share some links/provide an explanation as to why this is, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`, a generic type that is distinct from just plain `int`. Thus, you can't return a `Nullable<int>` in a method specified to return `int`.

`object`, like other reference types, is nullable by itself and doesn't need to be wrapped in `Nullable<T>`, and thus can match the return type of `getObject()` and be returned without error.

Comment: and if get getInt() return type was object. Then Nullable<int> would also match the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Chris' answer except the nullable object part.

The `?` is just syntax sugar for the `Nullable<T>` generic type. This type implicitly inherits the type `object`. Because `Nullable<T>` inherits `object`, the nullable object can be returned as type `object`.

The `Nullable<T>` does not inherit `int` and therefore cannot be returned with a return type of `int`.

Here's whats actually going on

```
public class Example
{
    public int getInt()
    {
        Nullable<int> myInt = 2;

        return myInt; // <-- compiler error.
    }

    public object getObject()
    {
        Nullable<object> obj = new { };

        return obj; // <-- OK, no error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call this `getInt()` you are asking for an `int`, not for an `int?`. In this way, you can do this:

```
public int getInt()
{
        int? myInt = 2;

        if (myInt.HasValue)
        {
           return myInt.Value; // You must return .Value (int value)
        }
        else 
        { 
           /* You can dou something here, like change to default value and then return 'myInt.Value', p.e.*/ 
        }
        
}
```

Anyway, you can use `.HasValue` to know if a nullable attribute is null or not, and return the non-null value with `.Value`.

In the other way, when you ask for `getObject()`, you expect an object, wich can be any kind of type. This is why you have no errors on there.